# How do I make a circuit for a push switch that in order to turn on you need to press it 2 times?

Tags: led, digital-logic, switches, logic-gates, button

Is there any way to make a switch circuit that turn a led on by pressig it two times thank you...

Comment: What happens if you press three times? Is the same button supposed to turn the LED off?

Comment: The led is turned off when button is released

Comment: if contacts bounce from vibration then what is the must detect time and must ignore duration or don’t care just denounce input switch

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic same but with improved simulation and faster switch debounce time.

Only glitch is it may need power up reset.

[image]

1 second per division.

Comment: That was simply demonstrating switch debounce interval ignored below threshold which can be easy adjusted shorter if the switch permits. Does  it need explaining Theory of Op?

Comment: My last photo had errors in the arrows !

Answer (score 4):

Yes. But it depends on how complex or expensive you want your circuit. The simplest way for me is to use a micro-controller that listens for the first button press (pulled high) and a timeout of a couple hundred milliseconds in which you must press the button again before it accepts it as a valid sequence to turn on your LED.

Comment: sad but true...